# Sheaf cohomology in non-commutative setup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a sheaf of noncommutative associative algebras over a fixed field $k$. My questions are:

1) Does the category of modules over A have enough injective?

2) If we have an affirmative answer of question (1), then suppose $M$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf over $A$ then the first cohomology of M: $H^1(X,M)$ is $0$?

I learn the cohomology of module over a scheme $X$ in Hartshorne book. But when we deform the structure sheaf $O_X$ of $X$, then does the cohomology theory still hold for quasi-coherent sheaves? Would you please tell me some books/papers about this kind of theory.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: For any sheaf $A$ of rings whatsoever (commutative or not), the category of $A$-modules has enough injectives.

Comment: thank you. where can I find a proof for this?

Comment: You can deduce it from the case where $A = \mathbb{Z}$. See the last paragraph [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/400558/5191).

Comment: This has been answered at MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132107